# OpenCV : Imshow window not appearing the second time when destroyed with destroyWindow

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, websocket, imshow

I'm using websocket request to run the below function in python to open webcam but it works only for the first time when my pyhton client gets connected to the server. When I press *'q'* and try to call the function again without loosing the connection, it gets stuck in the line *cv2.imshow('frame', frame)* and nothing happens.

When I re-run the python code, disconnect and connect again to the server, it works fine but only for once. Please somebody help me !!!

```
def stream():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if  key == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture and destroy frame window
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you try to explicitly call namedWindow? Can you try to give an individual name for each new call?

Comment: can you try to remove VideoCapture and instead use a static image? The idea is tgat maybe yozr captired device has problems in closing and re-opening. This test could make this visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by doing all opencv stuffs on the main thread and all other operations in a new thread. In your case, you can maintain a dictionary of frames and update frame after reading it. And in main thread, maintain a `while (True)` loop and call `cv2.imshow`.